# ARM PC overwritten with incorrect value in buffer overflow

Tags: arm, gdb, buffer-overflow, stack-smash, program-counter

I am working on stack smashing on ARM and I have a buffer declared as:

char buff[12];

in my code.

In order to find the location where the PC gets overwritten  in gdb I write

**AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFF** to buff

I expected DDDD to overwrite FP(r11) as **0x44444444** (and it execute correct) but the PC was overwitten with **0x45454544** (**instead of 0x45454545**)

Does anyone have an idea why the last byte is D(44) instead of E(45)? I have tried longer input but the value in the PC always drops by a few bits.

Screenshot 
[of GDB output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvE51.jpg)

Comment: "overwitten with 0x45454544 (instead of 0x45454544)" They're the same value. Did you mean "overwitten with 0x45454544 (instead of 0x4545454**5**)"?

Comment: Have you tried printing the address of `&buff[0]`?

Comment: instead of 0x45454545!

Comment: the lsbits of the pc are reserved/special you cant set the two lsbits in arm mode they are stripped off you cant set the lsbit in thumb mode it is stripped off going into thepc.

Comment: as also with the stack pointer(s) if you want to do some hacking do some hacking that actually works for the architecture.  random values wont do it.

Comment: How do you load those bytes into `PC` exactly? Is it through an `LDM`, `MOV`, `BX`, etc..? In any case, the ARM reference manual contains general rules regarding writes to `PC`, as well as instruction-specific notes that complement/supplant those general rules.

Comment: @old_timer I actually wanted to place an address to a function at 0x45454545 using something like  python -c 'print "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD" + "\x88\x12\x45\x04"'. Though it didn't work as expected.

Comment: @Michael. I entered the input from the command line to fill the 12 bytes buffer with 24bytes.

Comment: Sure, but by what instruction did you then transfer 4 of those bytes into the PC register?

Comment: @Michael I typed in AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFF (the program uses scanf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PC register cannot hold an odd value - the LSB are forced to 0 to ensure the address is aligned.

Comment: Does that mean the content is still equivalent to EEEE(0x45454545)?

Comment: in arm mode the address has to be four byte aligned in thumb mode two byte aligned.  in neither case can the lsbit be set, for arm mode bit 1 cannot be set.  the bits are stripped when they are loaded into the pc, the pc does not have that or those bits set.

Comment: it is pretty easy to check  add r0,r0,pc.